# How to avoid repeat of url when calling the action on same page using MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I created a Search in my layout. When user enters the word and clicks on search button , results show up in different page (ResultView). But when I'm in ResultView , I try to make an another search with different word this time , I get an error. When my url was /Content/Search/lorem , it becomes /Content/Search/Content/Search/lorem . How can I avoid this and search after refresh ?

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch"  class="tftextinput2" name="searchKey" size="21" maxlength="120" value="">
<input type="button" value=">" onclick='redirectOnClick()' class="tfbutton2" id="srcButton">
                

<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(document.getElementById('txtSearch').value)

$(document).ready(function() {
  function redirectOnClick() {
    document.location = 'Content/Search/' + $(searchboxID).val();
  }
  var test = document.getElementById('srcButton').addEventListener("click", redirectOnClick);
  var searchboxID = "#txtSearch";
  //location.reload();
});
</script>
```

Comment: `document.location = 'Content/` says: *add Content/ to the current url* - no doubt your first page was just `/` url -  try with `document.location = '/Content...`.   If you're using Razor/asp.net-mvc then you should be using `@Url.Action("Search")` instead of hardcoding the search path.

Comment: @freedomn-m It's not going to the Search when I use this. I even used @Url.Action("Search","Content")

Comment: What does it *render* as?  View-source or inspect element in the browser.

Comment: @freedomn-m when I click on search it says  redirectOnClick is not defined in browser inspect

Comment: That's a very different issue.   I've reformatted your code so it's clearer to see - `function redirectOnClick` is defined *within* doc.ready - so it's *scope* is doc.ready only - ie can only be called from within doc.ready.  As you're using `onclick=` the function for the onclick= *must* be defined globally - ie move `function redirectOnClick() { ... ` to *outside* doc.ready.